# JPA 2.1 CriteriaQuery between Date

Tags: jpa, between, criteriaquery

How can I use CriteriaQuery with BETWEEN clause in Date? I have tried this without success;

the DAO method:

```
public List<Registry> listRegistry(Date init){
    List<Registry> registrys = null;
    try{
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = getEm().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Registry> c = cb.createQuery(Registry.class);
        Root<Registry> registry= c.from(Registry.class);

        // get error here; "The method get(String) in the type Path<Registry> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date, Date)"
        c.select(registry).where(cb.between(registry.get("dateEntry", init, currentDate)));

        registrys = getEm().createQuery(c).getResultList();

    }
    catch (NoResultException x) {
        //does nothing
    }
    return registrys;
}
```

and the Entity Class Registry:

```
@Entity
public class Registry {

@GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
@Id
private int id;

private Date dateEntry;

// getters and setters .....
}
```

With these error  : "The method get(String) in the type Path is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date, Date)" ; How can I solve this?

Comment: It's a typo, review your code here `registry.get("dateEntry", init, currentDate))`. I think it should be `cb.between(registry.get("dateEntry"), init, currentDate)`;

Comment: sorry dont understand you ; I think i already done this way mentioned from you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing your code, it looks like a typo.

You have

```
// get error here; "The method get(String) in the type Path<Registry> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date, Date)"
c.select(registry).where(cb.between(registry.get("dateEntry", init, currentDate)));
```

Which is a compiler error, means that you're trying to call `get(String)`in the type `Path<Registry>` with the arguments `(String, Date, Date)`

Look at the javadoc of
[CriteriaBuilder.between(Expression,Value,Value)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#between(javax.persistence.criteria.Expression,%20Y,%20Y)), this is the method you need to call with 3 arguments not [Path.get(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get(java.lang.String)).

It should look something like this.

```
 Path<Date> dateEntryPath = registry.get("dateEntry");
 Predicate predicate = cb.between(dateEntryPath,init,currentDate);
 c.select(registry).where(predicate);
```

Comment: I will test in a few hours and I let you know if solves the problem; glad to your answer!